# Effect of blank template matching all elements in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I am looking at someone else's `XSL` and I can see this at the top of the document:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*" />
```

What is the effect of this, and does it make sure no elements are processed that don't have a matching template?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the effect of this

The effect of this is that when you apply templates to an element or an attribute, and there is no other template that matches the node with a higher priority, then the node is suppressed and nothing is written to the output.

> does it make sure no elements are processed that don't have a matching template?

It depends on what you mean by "processed". An element that does not have a matching template could be still processed - in the sense of passing information to the output - by a template matching its ancestor or descendant element, or by a named template, or by a key, to name a few examples.

In addition, the above template is applied only in the absence of a [mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#modes). If you apply templates to an element in another mode, and no matching template in that mode is found, then the above template will NOT be applied and the element will be processed by the built-in template rules, resulting in its child text nodes being copied to the output.

Comment: To add to this, it's a typical coding pattern when you want your stylesheet to copy selected parts of the input, and discard everything else. In XSLT 3.0 you can express this intent using `<xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-skip"/>`.

Comment: Why does the above template have a low priority?  Is it because it uses `*` ?

Comment: In general, the more specific a match pattern is, the higher the template's priority. However, there are exceptions - see the last note here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#default-priority